# Word for having the same rank

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a triplet of adjectives to describe "having lesser rank, having equal rank, having greater rank"?  For example, is there a word for something that is neither inferior, nor superior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Peer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peer)*** (noun)is used to express the concept of equal rank:

> - A person who has equal standing with another or others, as in rank, class, or age: children who are easily influenced by their peers.

AHD

***[Coequal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/coequal)*** (adjective):

> - Equal with one another; having the same rank or importance.
>   ‘*coequal partners*’

ODO

Comment: That's great, but I'm looking for an adjective.

Comment: Wow!  That's amazing.  Can I ask how you found it?

Answer (score 1):

The word ***commensurate*** should satisfy your requirement of *same rank* (something that is neither inferior, nor superior).

M-W:

> **[commensurate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commensurate)**
>   *adjective*
>
> : equal or similar to something in size, amount, or degree
>
> Her new position came with a commensurate level of responsibility.